# Is it possible to switch Spotlight in OS X to using Google?

Tags: spotlight, google

Spotlight (in Yosemite) has the ability to search the web. However, this only works with Bing. Is it possible to switch it to using Google?

Comment: Is the Search with Google still in the syst pref Keyboard shortcuts-Services Enabled?

Comment: @Buscar웃: Surprisingly, yes

Comment: and? can you disable the Bing ?

Comment: Web Search engines is a very big business. The Google is all about that, and how they made the big buck. Apple has decided to go with Microsoft Bing for purely financial reasons, and they did not make it easy for users to change it.

Comment: Buscar, Apple's reasons for using Bing over Google may be financial, but I would suggest you add "in my opinion" before making accusations. Neither of us work at Apple and therefore neither of us know for sure what Apple's motivations for the switch were.

Comment: tubedogg, It might me good to add `in my opinion`, however, it is also OK to let the people figure out that it is opinion, not fact.  It's not that hard to do, and adding "In my opinion" just adds a "politically correct" side to it.

Comment: @tubedogg As far I know anything I say here is in "my opinion" unless i quote the source. I do not officially represent Apple and have not claimed to do so. Please read the press to get your self up to speed on the Internet Browsers business and competition. As for why would Apple drop the world biggest search engine, feel free to take a guess? a hint..it is not technical.

Comment: @Buscar웃 To me, a statement like "Apple has decided to go with Microsoft Bing for purely financial reasons" sounds like you are presenting fact, even though you did not cite a source. Saying "It seems like Apple has decided..." or "Apple appears to have decided..." or "In my opinion, Apple has decided..." makes it clear that it is opinion, whether informed or otherwise. I did not state that you said you represent Apple, but to a user reading the site, it could appear that you (someone with high reputation here) have knowledge of the situation that you state you do not actually have.

Comment: We all make statements here without citing sources that are indeed facts - clicking the Apple menu then clicking App Store launches the Mac App Store. It's a fact, and it doesn't become my opinion just because I didn't cite a source. I don't need to read anything about Apple or Google or Bing to know that your statement is _likely_ correct. I wasn't arguing the probability of it being accurate, simply stating that it seemed like you were presenting it as absolute fact.

Comment: @tubedog if you read between the lines in this article you will find the indication about this been about business/Money. http://www.wired.com/2014/10/how-to-fix-os-x-yosemite-search/ !

Comment: @Buscar웃 I am not sure which lines I am supposed to be reading between to discover that Apple's motive in this change was financial, considering that the article does not speculate on Apple's reasons for choosing Bing. I have also already said that your statement is _likely_ correct. There are two other possible reasons for Apple's choice - one is to preserve user privacy (Google likely would not be desperate enough to agree without receiving a lot of the information Apple states is now discarded). The other is simply to continue to distance themselves from Google. [continued]

Comment: [continued] On privacy, iOS is quickly becoming the anti-Android, with the assumption being that Google is tracking everything you do while Apple introduces features that prevent tracking, or even your device being able to be opened by law enforcement.

Comment: unfortunately, Flashlight doesn't work in El Capitan: https://github.com/nate-parrott/Flashlight/issues/537

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to get suggestions from Google, but it is possible to do a Google (or any other supported search engines) search from Spotlight.

Select your favorite search engine in the Safari preferences. Then in spotlight you type the term to be searched and then do the search with ⌘ + B.

This works even if your default browser is not Safari, but will use Safari's default search engine.

Answer (score 10):

In OS X 10.10 someone has made a spotlight plugin which has unofficially reversed engineered the API necessary to add new search engines.
i.e. google. The project is called flashlight.
It comes out of the box with a lot of plugins, including google.
To use it, you start spotlight and enter g yosemite, for example, which does a google search for "yosemite"

This open-source app is hosted on git hub and has releases which mean you just install the .app file, as usual. However, it's not signed so you may need to go to system preferences -> security & privacy and choose to allow the app to open (which you do after starting it and getting the error message that the app is not from the app store). Assuming you trust the app and/or my recommendation. You may like to visit the github site and see how many people have starred this application, to give you some sense of confidence.
download here:
http://flashlight.nateparrott.com/

github:
https://github.com/nate-parrott/Flashlight#flashlight

Comment: This is really great. I was using Alfred for similar functionality, but if I can bundle a lot of it directly into spotlight then that's one less app to worry about. :-) Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

You might check out [Google Quick Search Box](https://code.google.com/p/qsb-mac/downloads/list). From their description:

> Quick Search Box is an open source search box that allows you to
>   search data on your computer and across the web. With Quick Search Box
>   you can search for information from just about anywhere. You can then
>   perform actions on the search results, such as launching applications,
>   emailing friends, or playing a song.

Otherwise, OS X Yosemite still has a shortcut in `System Preferences` >> `Keyboard` >> `Shortcuts` >> Under `Searching`, `Search with Google`

However, the short answer to your question is no.  You cannot use spotlight to directly search Google.

Answer (score 1):

Open Safari, open preferences > search > Make sure your search engine is set to Google. Also, make sure to include Spotlight Suggestions. This should do the trick. I have attached my settings, which allow me to use Google with Spotlight. If you need more help, comment and I'll be interested to help! My settings:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't appear to work in Yosemite

Comment: That is strange... Are you on the latest version?

Comment: There is only one version of Yosemite.

Comment: 10.10 or 10.10. 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, confirming that this no longer works in the most current version of Yosemite.

Comment: test on big sur, it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search more than google, an interesting alternative is [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com), it's pretty close to spotlight, but has a lot more options (especially if you buy the power pack.